# Media Recorder is crashing on stopping it

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am creating a voice chat application in which I has to record a sound from mic. When I start recording it starts fine but when I stop the recording it crashes at the first time and at the second time when I record the sound and stop it works fine and create the audio file in my external storage what is the issue which is giving issue for the first time.

**ChatActivity.java**

```
package com.example.usamaakmal.npproject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Timer;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ToggleButton recButton;
    MediaRecorder recorder = null;
    boolean recoredAlreadClicked = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        this.setTitle("Chat Room");

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/NPProject");
        if (!dir.isDirectory()){
            dir.mkdir();
        } else {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    }
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.send:

                    return true;
                case R.id.play:
                    playRecording();
                    return true;
                case R.id.record:
                    if (recoredAlreadClicked){
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mic_black_24dp);
                        item.setTitle("Record");
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Stopping Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            stopRec();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        recoredAlreadClicked = !recoredAlreadClicked;
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp);
                        item.setTitle("Stop");
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Starting Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startRec();
                        recoredAlreadClicked = !recoredAlreadClicked;
                        return true;
                    }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }

    public void playRecording() {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/NPProject/audio.m4a");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }


    private void startRec() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.release();
        }
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/NPProject/"+ SocketHelper.getName() +"-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".m4a");
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("giftlist", "io problems while preparing [" +
                    getFilesDir() + "]: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void stopRec() throws IOException {
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
        }

       // Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, ""+convertAudioToByte().length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public byte[] convertAudioToByte() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/NPProject/audio.m4a");
        FileChannel fc = inputStream.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)fc.size());
        fc.read(buffer);
        return   buffer.array();
    }

    public void convertByteToAudio(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/NPProject/audio.m4a");
        outputStream.write(b);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

**This is the stack trace of the activity what i got when the app is crashed**

```
E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 4
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.usamaakmal.npproject, PID: 12556
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException
                      at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_stop(Native Method)
                      at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:1244)
                      at com.example.usamaakmal.npproject.ChatActivity.stopRec(ChatActivity.java:138)
                      at com.example.usamaakmal.npproject.ChatActivity.access$000(ChatActivity.java:31)
                      at com.example.usamaakmal.npproject.ChatActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(ChatActivity.java:71)
                      at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:182)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
                      at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:95)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22459)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: Can you upload your logs fully

Comment: Also, please share the project manifest.

Comment: Did you request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: Thank you for your support guys i solved the issue. @Bek

Comment: Thank you for your support guys i solved the issue. @ManmeetP

Comment: Thank you for your support guys i solved the issue. @nhoxbypass

Comment: @Usama, can you please share the solution you opted. It will be helpful for all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I solve this issue by giving permission application to record mic in settings**, I didn't add run time permissions so this is the issue.